# How to retrieve return code from sp_addlinkedserver?

Tags: sql-server-2000, linked-server

I am trying to link the server

```
Exec sp_addlinkedserver 'servername', ......
```

How will i retrieve its result (return value 0 or 1) in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Insert into MyTable
exec sp_addlinkedserver 'servername'